# In Fish, is it possible to ignore all Git related commands?

Tags: git, shell, fish

I know fish doesn't remember commands that start with a `space`, but if it possible to add a rule which ignores Git commands?

Comment: In bash, there's `$HISTIGNORE`. I'm not sure about fish, though.

Comment: I don't see anything in the [documentation](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/#history-search) about anything like this. Just about the leading space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by [mnagle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34003506/125549), but with fish-specific features:

If you add an [abbreviation](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#abbr) for `git` to "`git`", then fish will insert a space before every git command for you!

```
abbr -a git ' git'
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this hack: `alias git=" git"`

Comment: PS: I did this with ZSH (overlooked the fish part in your question). Possibly it works in fish as well with a slightly adjusted syntax.

Comment: Won't work as expected, because the git *alias* will be in history.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nuclear option, but it might be your best option:

```
function git
    command git $argv

    set history_items (history --search --prefix git)
    for item in $history_items
        history --delete $item
    end
end
```